# Erlang upper case and lower case sort

Tags: sorting, erlang, uppercase, lowercase

the question about a comparison of the upper and lower case..how can i do that in my sort function.any idea?

Ex: Inputfile : " I am Happy! "

Outputfile:

```
Happy!
I
am
```

thats what's happen with my program, but i would like so have:

```
am
I
Happy
```

My code:

```
-module(wp)
-compile([export_all]). % Open the File

sortFile(File1,File2) ->
    {ok, File_Read} = file:read_file(File1),
    % making a list
    Liste = string:tokens(binary_to_list(File_Read), "\n "),
    % isort List
    Sort_List = isort(Liste),
    ISort = string:join(Sort_List,"\n"),
    %Written in the File.
    {ok,Datei_Schreiben} = file:open(File2, write),
    file:write(File_Write, Isort),
    file:close(File_Write).

isort([]) -> [];
isort([X|XS])-> insert(X, isort(XS)).

insert(Elem, []) -> [Elem];
insert(Elem, [X|XS]) when Elem= [Elem,X|XS];
insert(Elem, [X|XS]) -> [X|insert(Elem,XS)].
```

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this:

```
qsort1([]) -> [];
qsort1([H|T]) -> 
     qsort1([X || X <- T, string:to_lower(X) < string:to_lower(H)]) 
     ++ [H] 
     ++ qsort1([X || X <- T, string:to_lower(X) >= string:to_lower(H)]).


7> qsort1(["I", "am","Happy"]).
   ["am","Happy","I"]
```

I believe that "happy" sorts less than "i"

```
8> "happy" < "i".
true
```

which is why my sorted order is a little differenct than your original post.

Answer (score 1):

When there is at least `N*log2(N)` comparisons in sorting there is not necessary to make `N*log2(N)` but only `N` case transformations. (Almost all perl developers knows this trick.)

```
{ok, Bin} = file:read_file(?INPUT_FILE),
Toks = string:tokens(binary_to_list(Bin),"\n "),
Result = [[X,$\n] || {_,X} <- lists:sort([{string:to_lower(X), X} || X<-Toks])],
file:write_file(?OUTPUT_FILE, Result).
```

BTW `lists:sort/1` merge sort has granted `N*log2(N)` and is pretty efficient in contrary to concise but less efficient quick sort implementation. What worse, quick sort has `N^2` worst case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare low cap in your sort function:

```
(nitrogen@127.0.0.1)25> F= fun(X,Y) -> string:to_lower(X) < string:to_lower(Y) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.111823515>
(nitrogen@127.0.0.1)26> lists:sort(F,["I","am","Happy"]).                          
["am","Happy","I"]
(nitrogen@127.0.0.1)27>
```

EDIT:

In your code, the function that allows to sort the list are the operators > and < (if you want to see replicated string one of them should include =, otherwise you will do a usort). If you want to use a different comparison you can define it in a normal or anonymous function and then use it in the quicksort:

```
mycompare(X,Y) ->
    string:to_lower(X) < string:to_lower(Y).

quicksort  ([])->[];
           ([X|XS])-> quicksort([Y||Y<-XS,mycompare(X,Y)])++[X]++quicksort([Y||Y<-XS,mycompare(X,Y) == false]).
```

Comment: Hello Pascal, thanks a lot for answer, but could show me be how cani  implement  into the quicksort for exemple.                                quicksort([])->[];                                 
([X|XS])-> quicksort([Y||Y<-XS,Y<X])++[X]++quicksort([Y||Y<-XS,Y>X]).

Comment: Hi Marley, I completed the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Now, depending on whether you are on `Windows` or `Unix/Linux`, the lines in the files will be ended with different characters. Lets go with windows where its normally `\r\n`. Now assuming the input files are not too big, we can read them at once into a binary. The stream of data we get must be split into lines, then each line split into words (spaces). If the input file is very big and cannot fit in memory, then you will have to read it, line by line, in which case you might need an IN-Memory buffer to hold all the words ready for sorting, this would require `ETS Table`, or `Memcached` (an option i wont illustrate here).
 Lets write the code

```
-module(sick_sort).
-compile(export_all).
-define(INPUT_FILE,"C:/SICK_SORT/input.txt").
-define(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH,"C:/SICK_SORT/").
-define(OUTPUT_FILENAME,"output.txt").

start()->
    case file:read_file(?INPUT_FILE) of
        {ok,Binary} ->
            %% input file read
            AllLines = string:tokens(binary_to_list(Binary),"\r\n"),
            SortedText = lists:flatten([XX ++ "\r\n" || XX <- lists:sort(string:tokens(AllLines," "))]),
            EndFile = filename:join(?OUTPUT_FILE_PATH,?OUTPUT_FILENAME),
            file:write_file(EndFile,SortedText),
            ok;
        Error -> {error,Error}
    end.
```

That should work. Change the macros in the source file to suit your settings and then, just run `sick_sort:start().`